# Reviewing query from which Virtual Layer was originated in QGIS

Tags: qgis, sql, query, virtual-layer

I created a Virtual Layer by going in `Layer > Add Layer > Add or Edit Virtual Layer`. This new layer was created by building a query on another layer I had in my project.

Ho can I check, afterwards, what's the query from which this new Virtual Layer was created?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the layer Panel, right mouse click on the `Virtual Layer > Edit Virtual Layer...`. The window containing the query opens and you can see or modify the query.